# Decrypt Environment Variables using Apache2

Tags: apache2, shibboleth, shibboleth-sp

I'd like to store private encrypted information into an environment variable and then decrypt it in apache2 config file, but i haven't found any example to look for an i have no idea on how to implement this

i thought about something like this:

```
#decrypt somehow mails value and then use it
<Location /example>
Authtype shibboleth
ShibRequestSetting requireSession 1
Require shib-attr mail ${mails}
</Location>
```